# Chat removes ´ when trying to type code to someone

Tags: support, chat, markdown, code-formatting

I am not sure if this should be a bug report or a feature request.

I am trying to help someone and I keep trying to type

```
`name` `=` 'Group project drive'
```

but the ´ are being removed making it hard to help the person.  [Link to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198318/discussion-between-devstarlight-and-daimto)

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused. ` and ´ aren't the same thing. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: Look again zoom in the characters are not the same one is vertical the other on slanted

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ` are used to [indicate inline code](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#formatting), just like in posts or in comments. Typing

```
`name`
```

results in `name`, this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

If you want these backticks to be displayed instead, escape them by typing a backslash first, like this:

```
\`name\`
```